# printing a php variable as it is : with all the special characters

Tags: php

Ok I need to find out what is contained inside a PHP variable and I have it to do it visually, is there a function to display whatever that's contained in a string as it is?

For example :

```
$TEST = '&nbsp' . "\n" . ' ';
```

if I use echo the output will be :

while i want it to be :

```
&nbsp\n&nbsp
```

is it possible? (I hope I was clear enough)

ty

Comment: may be you can do this by htmlspecialchars_decode but I am not sure.

Comment: Incidentally, there should be a ; after the &nbsp if we're being strict

Comment: `&nbsp;` and `(space)` are different characters. You'll definitely need to do this replacement  manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$TEST = '&nbsp;' . "\n" . ' ';
echo json_encode(htmlspecialchars($TEST));
```

Note that `json_encode` has third agrument in PHP 5.4.

Comment: WOW!! Exactly what i was looking for, the output came out as :

    "\r\nlol"

turns out \r was the character that was messing with my code....
thank you so much :)

Comment: An elegant solution! A note for others looking for an identical solution - json_encode is available for PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump()` should do the work for you?

**Example:**

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($variable);
echo "</pre>";
```

Use `<pre>` to keep the format structure, makes it alot easier to read.

**Resources:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: `var_dump("\n");` will not display `\n`. Which is what the asker wants.

Comment: true, json_encode(htmlspecialchars($TEST)) works nicely thou.

Comment: Ok, my bad. But question isn't crystal clear unfortunately. I focused on "show contained in a string" or variable and then var_dump is great.

Answer (score 0):

Try print_r, var_dump or var_export functions, you'll find them very handy for this kind of needs!

Comment: I tried it but the special characters still remained hidden :(

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

or

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
$TEST = '&nbsp' . "\n" . ' ';
echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace('\n','\\n', $TEST), ENT_QUOTES);
```

or

```
$TEST = '&nbsp' . "\n" . ' ';
echo htmlentities(str_replace('\n','\\n',$TEST), ENT_QUOTES);
```

You may have to encode the newlines manually. If you want to encode them as actual newlines you can use nl2br. Or string replace these characters with your preference. Update: as I have added to the code per request. String replace special characters you wish to see like newlines and tabs.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I am not asking you what to read. I am asking what does this code print out.

Comment: I'd rather you and others went to the docs and read what these functions do than spoonfeeding you the results of 2 lines of code. This will encourage learning.

Comment: I'd rather you actually run the code you suggests **and compare the output with an example provided by the OP**. You'd be surprised.

Comment: Then would you care to point out the shortcomings and be direct about the issues you are finding.

Comment: Shortcoming #1 is that \n is still a newline, not \n as the OP requested

Answer (score -4):

assuming you want it for the debugging purposes, let me suggest to use `urlencode()`. I am using it to make sure I don't miss any invisible character.
The output is not that clear but it works for me.